# DB2 join doesn't want to execute

Tags: database, db2

I'm using AQT connected to a DB2 database. I'm trying to join 2 tables on columns that are exactly the same type and length (varchar2) and they are NULLABLE and NOT UNIQUE.

```
select count(*) from table1 a
inner join table2 b
on a.column1 = b.column1
```

end the error I get is "a.column1 is not valid in the context it is used"

So is it because the columns are not keys, NULLABLE and NOT UNIQUE or there is something else?

Comment: Can you post the DDL of both tables ?

Comment: Apparently there's a syntax error in your actual query, but since you chose not to show it, it's not possible to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: If you post the *actual* SQL that has the error, we stand a much better chance of helping you.